# Algorithm for genogram

Tags: ruby, recursion, graph-algorithm

I am developing a ruby program that should be able to draw a genogram on a web page.

I am therefore looking for an algorithm for drawing a genogram or a similar tree-structure. 
I prefer an algorithm in ruby but also other languages will do or some references explaning the principles behind such an algorithm

A recursive algorithm  in c++ has been published here but  it is not documented in a way that allows me to use it.

Any help about how to implement a genogram would be much apriciated

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you trying to model the data for the genogram, figure out node placement on a surface, or find a way to render it into a browser? Each one of these is a challenge by itself.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the canonical work on rendering trees is "Drawing Dynamic Trees" by Sven Moen. You should be able to find the paper or an implementation of his polyline algorithm with a bit of googling.

You could also have a look at [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) as that can handle trees as well as arbitrary graphs.

Comment: Thanks That helped I found both the original artical http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=56447, a java implementation http://samskivert.com/internet/deep/1997/05/07/ and an overview article with several solutions http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.11/11.04/CPPTrees/index.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure I came across Moen's work through the "Brighton Tree Widget for Tcl/Tk" mentioned in the samskivert.com link.